# MVC NavBar is hiding page title and other controls when min-width: 768px and max-width: 991px

Tags: c#, css, model-view-controller, web-applications

I am using the MVC's default Bootstrap. How can I make my page move down below the nav bar when the device screen is in between 767px and 991px?

[Issue screenshot attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2w2F.png)

Comment: I dont think this has anything to do with C#

Comment: True. Just need help. Its urgent. Its bootstrap actually.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can handle this by two ways one by css as below

 @media only screen and (min-width: 767px) and (max-width: 991px) {
.yourContainerClass{
margin-top:200px;//Here 200 is your header height for screen between 767px and 991px need to replace with actual height
}
}


Other way is using jquery as below

 var headerHeight=$('.yourHeaderClass').height();
        // headerHeight+=15; // maybe add an offset too?
        $('.yourContainerClass').css('margin-top',headerHeight+'px');
```